# Result of the "R Script" without ColumnNames

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm going crazy!
I'm using Azure Machine Learning and R Script. I deploy it as Web Service. I use sample code based on HttpClient.

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var scoreRequest = new
            {
                Inputs = new Dictionary<string, StringTable>() {
                    {
                        "input1",
                        new StringTable()
                        {
                            ColumnNames = new string[] {
                                    "experts_estimates",
                                    "experts_share_of_unique_information",
                                    "avg_correlation",
                                    "point_a",
                                    "point_b",
                                    "is_export_mode"
                            },
                            Values = new string[,] {
                                {
                                    expertsEstimatesStr,
                                    expertsShareOfUniqueInformationStr,
                                    avgCorrelationStr,
                                    pointAStr,
                                    pointBStr,
                                    isExportModeStr
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                }
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);

            // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock
            // if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
            // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false)
            // so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
            // For instance, replace code such as:
            //      result = await DoSomeTask()
            // with the following:
            //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp,
                // which are useful for debugging the failure
                var headers = response.Headers.ToString();
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                throw new Exception(responseContent, new Exception(headers));
            }
        }
```

and when I run code from Visual Studio I get:
[image]
but when I run code from Azure App Service I get:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is adding "edit metadata" module inside the model and rename the output columns. It'll be easy than using the code to name the columns.